# How to use both a database and path-parsing in one request handler, in Axum 0.5?

Tags: rust, rust-axum

I currently have working code:

```
    // build our application with a route
    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/api/:start/:tokens/:left/:top/:right/:bottom", get(stats))
        .route("/dbtest", get(dbtest))
        .layer(Extension(pool))
        ;
...
// we can extract the connection pool with `Extension`
async fn dbtest(
    Extension(pool): Extension<PgPool>,
) -> Result<String, (StatusCode, String)> {
    sqlx::query_scalar("select 'hello world from pg'")
        .fetch_one(&pool)
        .await
        .map_err(internal_error)
}
...
async fn stats(
    Path((start, tokens, left, top, bottom, right)): Path<(DateTime<Utc>, DashVec, u32, u32, u32, u32)>,
) -> String {
    format!("{} {:?} {:?} {:?}", start.to_rfc3339(), tokens, (left, top), (right, bottom))
}
```

How do I make a handler which can use *both* the database `pool` and parse its `Path`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define them as separate arguments:

```
async fn combined(
    Extension(pool): Extension<PgPool>,
    Path((start, tokens, left, top, bottom, right)): Path<(DateTime<Utc>, DashVec, u32, u32, u32, u32)>,
) -> Result<String, (StatusCode, String)> {
    println!("{} {:?} {:?} {:?}", start.to_rfc3339(), tokens, (left, top), (right, bottom));
    sqlx::query_scalar("select 'hello world from pg'")
        .fetch_one(&pool)
        .await
        .map_err(internal_error)
}
```

`Path` and `Extension` are [*extractors*](https://docs.rs/axum/0.5.17/axum/extract/index.html) and a [handler](https://docs.rs/axum/0.5.17/axum/index.html#handlers) function may have *"zero or more extractors as arguments"*.